# large json files with datatables performance enhancement

Tags: javascript, datatables

for JSON files > 100 MB. 
Is it possible if I split them to 100 files each with 1 MB so that I can pass them to Datatables so that it loads each file per page for performance enhancement ?

is this even a valid request ? -- if no. is there anything can be done for perfomance enhancement ? (notee the the json file is local)

Comment: You have to test. Performance depends on hardware of computer that's going to parse that 100MB json and display it. It's quite different if you're using a laptop with `i3` CPU or a desktop computer with an `i7` or similar. There's no indication *why* you need 100 megabytes to be loaded, so the first thing that I'd do is ask myself whether 100 megabytes of JSON data is really what's needed. If you split it in chunks - it's probably going to be easier but in the end, you'll still transfer 100 megabytes and parse 100 megabytes in order to render it.

Comment: why you do not use a database?

Comment: in most cases the json file sizes/data are normal but in some cases it reaches that limit. that;s why I'm lookin for a solution to that